# PHP find how many days until the next repeated event from start time

Tags: php, calendar, intervals

I have a calendar with events that a user inputs from an install start date. 
These events are always repeating from the start date, every X days,months or years, and we do not know the end date. 
I need to find the next event that is happening in unix timestamp format.
I tried to figure out the built in PHP DateInterval classes but I couldn't figure out how to with no known ending date.

This is what I have so far

```
/* User Input */
$installdate="315558000";// 1st Jan 1980 
$Every = 1; // Could be 1 =>  
$DateOption = 'Months'; // Could be 'Days' 'Months' or 'Years'

#Possible user selections 
$DateJustify = array('Days'=>j,'Months'=>n,'Years'=>Y);

#Getting the next service date into printed variables for mktime
foreach($DateJustify as $keyDate => $dt ){
${$keyDate}=date($dt,$installdate);
if($DateOption == $keyDate )
${$keyDate} += $Every; 
}
```

This returns everything nice for timestamping with mktime but it just gives out the next date from the installdate. Ultimately seconds,minutes or hours do not matter since the installdate begins on a day

Comment: What should happen when `$installdate == 1364688000` (March 31st, 2013), `$Every == 1` and `$DateOptions == 'Months'`?

Comment: That would return the date into a month from March 31st, 2013. What would be the point of doing it?

Comment: That would be April 31st, 2013. There's no such date. Or would it be May 1st, 2013. Or maybe April 30th, 2013?

Comment: Forgive me, Im not quite sure I know what you're getting at. The code that I have I know wont work. I need someone to give me hints or re-write this

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class to convert string to time. Second parameter accepts time zone, use [DateTimeZone](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php).

```
$z = new DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin");
$d = new DateTime("next wed +3 day", $z);
echo $d->format("d.m.Y H:i");
echo $d->format("U"); # or echo $d->getTimestamp(); on PHP > 5.3.0
```

[DateTime::format()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method accepts format like [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

Comment: I just found out my server doesnt support the datetime function